# Fail to connect to the webservice by Using Okhttp

Tags: android, web-services, http, okhttp

I'm building an app that calls to a webservice. When i use `HttpUrlConnection` class to make a request to the webservice then it works, but i replace with `OkHttpClient` to make request then my app can't connect to the service, `OnFailure` method is always called with content: `"OnFailure: failed to connect to todolistmobileapp-env.ap-south-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/13.232.26.212 (port 80) after 4ms"`

Anyone tell me what problem i'm getting into?

```
public class RequestRegisterAuthor extends AppNetworkRequest {

    public static final String TAG = RequestRegisterAuthor.class.getSimpleName();

    private final String url = ToDoRestAPIs.baseRemoteHostUrl  + ToDoRestAPIs.registerAuthor;

    public RequestRegisterAuthor(APICallbackListener apiCallbackListener, Object jsonRequestBody){
        super(apiCallbackListener);
        request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                .addHeader(AppNetworkRequest.CONTENT_TYPE, AppNetworkRequest.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE)
                .post(RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(JSON_CONTENT_TYPE), jsonRequestBody.toString()))
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void makeBackEndRequest() {
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call,final IOException e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        apiCallbackListener.onFailureCallback(e.getMessage());
                        Log.e(TAG + "- OnFailure", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                try {
                    if(response.code() == 201){
                        responseObject = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(response.body().string(), Author.class);
                    }
                    else{
                        responseObject = new Error(response.code(), response.message());
                    }
                } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    responseObject = new Error(101, e.getMessage()); // pre-defined code.
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        apiCallbackListener.onSuccessCallback(REQUEST_TYPE.REQUEST_REGISTER_AUTHOR, responseObject);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    } }
```

Here is the logcat:

https://pastebin.com/3CNsGrPm

Comment: Can you share code and stack trace from logcat for OkHttpClient?

Comment: I have added my code and the logcat to the post.

Comment: Are you sure you have added `INTERNET` permission in Manifest ?

Comment: @adityakamble49: yeah, i had.

Comment: @duyhoang did you find a solution for this ? I am experiencing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe HttpUrlConnection uses OkHttp under the hood, could you post your code for both methods of connecting?